# How does this function return a value when it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, function, return

This function returns a value even when it shouldn't.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int foo(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else if(a<b)
        return b;
}
int main()
{
    int x=7,y=7;
    cout<<foo(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
7
```

Also it produces proper output only on a GCC compiler (I used Dev C++). Turbo C produced garbage value.
Can someone explain how this happens?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, that simple. What would you expect as return value actually?

Comment: Why should `7 `be the "proper output" ??

Comment: I'm not expecting anything. I was wondering how it returns 7.

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan it can return anything. If you really want to know why it returns 7 with GCC you have to look at the generated assembly code.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on not returning a value on all program control paths is *undefined*.

The compiler is allowed to do anything.

Didn't your compiler *warn* you of this? (GCC ought too, Turbo C possibly not on account of its age).

Comment: Ironically, Turbo c gives a warning while Dev C++ doesn't!

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan with proper settings Dev C++ will show a warning as well.

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan Switch on all warnings, and (assumed toolchain) GCC will warn you as well.